# Char vector saving more than its size

Tags: c, file, struct, archive

I have a program that reads a file and saves its content into the struct:

```
struct cadastro {
    char cod_segurado[3];
    char nome_segurado[50];
    char seguradora[50];
    char tipo_seguro[30];
};
```

Happens that after reading and saving the first field in the struct member **cod_segurado[3]** when the program reaches the second field it is being saved both in the first and second char **nome_segurado[50]** member of the struct. Why?

The code below shows how I am doing:

```
while (j < quant_registros){

    fread(&registro,sizeof(char),TAM_REG_ENTRADA,arquivo);

    while(conta_caracteres < TAM_COD_SEGURADO){
                if(registro[i] != '\0'){
                    cadastro[j].cod_segurado[k] = registro[i];
                    k++;
                }
                i++;
                conta_caracteres++;
            }

            k = 0;

            conta_caracteres = 0;

            while(conta_caracteres < TAM_NOME_SEGURADO){
                if(registro[i] != '\0'){
                    cadastro[j].nome_segurado[k] = registro[i];
                    k++;
                }
                i++;
                conta_caracteres++;
            }
        j++;
        i = 0;
        k = 0;
        conta_caracteres = 0;

}
```

So, in the end (for example), struct be like:

```
cod_segurado = '001Joao' //why saving Joao if size is 3?
nome_segurado = 'Joao'
seguradora = 'Example'
tipo_segurado = 'Example'
```

Comment: `if(registro[i] != '\0') { cadastro[j].cod_segurado[k] = registro[i];` hmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indent your code consistently.

This code block is wrong

```
            if(registro[i] != '\0'){
                cadastro[j].cod_segurado[k] = registro[i];
                k++;
            }
            i++;
            conta_caracteres++;
```

If the second character is a `'\0'`, your code goes off the rails from there. The if might work better as `if(k == 0 || cadastro[j].cod_segurado[k - 1] != '\0')` but that isn't this bug. Generally speaking we would rewrite this as

```
            cadastro[j].cod_segurado[k] = (k == 0 || cadastro[j].cod_segurado[k - 1] != '\0')
                    ? registro[i]
                    : 0;
            i++;
            conta_caracteres++;
```

so that the rest of the char array in the struct becomes zero filled.

You printed cod_segurado with `printf("%s", cadastro[j].cod_segurado);` Use `printf("%.3s", cadastro[j].cod_segurado);` thus limiting the string to at most 3 characters.

I'm always pleased to see this old format still used.

Comment: Thanks for your help!